# What changes must be made to the code inorder to prevent renderflow issue?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

In the code, I've wrapped the dropdown buttons within a row in a container, but when tried compressing the output horizontally it showed a render overflow issue. The problem arises when I try to make changes in the display in a horizontal manner. How could it be prevented?

The code I tried was :

```
> Container(
>                 padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 20, 12, 2),
>                 child: Row(
>                   children: <Widget>[
>                     Expanded(
>                       flex: 1,
>                       child: Column(
>                         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
>                         children: [
>                           Padding(
>                             padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 8),
>                             child: Text(
>                               "Manufacturing Date",
>                               style: TextStyle(
>                                 fontSize: 15.0,
>                                 fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
>                                 color: Colors.black,
>                               ),
>                             ),
>                           ),
>                           Container(
>                             padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 2, 8, 2),
>                             width: double.infinity,
>                             decoration: BoxDecoration(
>                               border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
>                               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
>                             ),
>                             child: Row(
>                               children: [
>                                 Expanded(
>                                   child: Text(
>                                     selectedDate,
>                                     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
>                                     textAlign: TextAlign.left,
>                                   ),
>                                 ),
>                                 Expanded(child:IconButton(
>                                   onPressed: () => _selectManufacturingDate(context),
>                                   icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today, color: Colors.blue),
>                                 ),)
>                               ],
>                             ),
>                           ),
>                         ],
>                       ),
>                     ),
>                     SizedBox(
>                       width: 20,
>                     ),
>                     Expanded(
>                       flex: 1,
>                       child: Column(
>                         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
>                         children: [
>                           Padding(
>                             padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 8),
>                             child: Text(
>                               "Expiry Date",
>                               style: TextStyle(
>                                 fontSize: 15.0,
>                                 fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
>                                 color: Colors.black,
>                               ),
>                             ),
>                           ),
>                           Container(
>                             width: double.infinity,
>                             padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 2, 8, 2),
>                             decoration: BoxDecoration(
>                               border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
>                               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
>                             ),
>                             child: Row(
>                               children: [
>                                 Expanded(
>                                   child: Text(
>                                     selectedDate2,
>                                     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
>                                     textAlign: TextAlign.left,
>                                   ),
>                                 ),
>                                 Expanded(child: IconButton(
>                                   onPressed: () => _selectExpiryDate(context),
>                                   icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today, color: Colors.blue),
>                                 ),),
>                               ],
>                             ),
>                           ),
>                         ],
>                       ),
>                     ),
>                     SizedBox(
>                       width: 20,
>                     ),
>                     Column(
>                       children: [
>                         if (manufacturingDate == null || expiryDate == null)
>                           Icon(Icons.remove, color: Colors.grey)
>                         else
>                           isProductValid
>                               ? Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.green)
>                               : Icon(Icons.cancel, color: Colors.red),
>                       ],
>                     ),
>                   ],
>                 ),
>               ),
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUv3S.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETs84.png)

Comment: provide the code correctly with indentation. Check with the Stackoverflow guidelines. Use ctrl+K to indent your code.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not clear. The only way you can change this is by reducing the value of the padding.

Comment: I have edited the code layout, please check once if you can help me with it.

Comment: Increase the dimensions of the container

Comment: The width of the container is double.infinity which is the maximum possible value

Answer (score 0):

--> in this case your code is not given properly but i will try to solve your render overflow error.

-->

```
Row(
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Text(
                "Manufacturing Date",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 2, 8, 2),
                // width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      "selectedDate",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      // onPressed: () = _selectManufacturingDate(context),
                      icon:
                          const Icon(Icons.calendar_today, color: Colors.blue),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 20),
              const Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 8),
                    child: Text(
                      "Expiry Date",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                // width: double.infinity,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 2, 8, 2),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      "selectedDate2",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      //  onPressed: () => _selectExpiryDate(context),
                      icon:
                          const Icon(Icons.calendar_today, color: Colors.blue),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 20),
              const Column(
                children: [
                  // if (manufacturingDate == null || expiryDate == null)
                  Icon(Icons.remove, color: Colors.grey),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: some code i am get in to comment please replace in your need to change.